# Search Page - Boolean Value - How to Search for True/False/Both?

Tags: search, boolean

I have a search page where one of the search options is a Boolean.  Right now, the search option is a checkbox, so the user can search for either `True` or `False`, but not for both.  What is a best practice for creating this search option that will allow the user to search for True, False, or Both?

The only thing I can come up with is a dropdown that has Yes, No, Both.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the dropdown - Yes/No/Both.  Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: I would say that its more elegant than using a checkbox for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I see is adding an option to activate / deactivate this search option. When deactivated, it will search for both.

If you stick with the dropdown, I'll use Any instead of Both.